# Access 97 - how to edit/explore existing toolbar?

Tags: ms-access, toolbar

My current job is updating an existing Access97-Project. I haven't worked with Access in a long time and i can't find out, how i can explore a toolbar called "sbmbDrucken" which is obviously user-created. I just need access to the action or the code which is called by the buttons...

Is there any menu entry i missed or do i need special code for self-inspection?

TIA!

Answer (score 1):

There are three different ways for menus/toolbars to be instantiated:

1. the old way, using macros. Before A95, this was the only way, so a lot of older apps (i.e., those converted from earlier versions) may still use macros for the menus.
2. defining them by hand, using the CUSTOMIZE function that you get when you right click on a toolbar in Access.
3. in code, using the Application.Commandbar object.

For the first you can browse your macros and see if any of them are menu macros.

For the last, you can do a search in the code for CommandBar.

For the second, just look at them through the built-in menu customization tools. Keep in mind that you may have to check them off to get them to be visible, and that the list is in no rational order. Likewise, some menus/toolbars are hidden from the customization interface. Also, you might need to look at the CUSTOM toolbar menu item.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Access 97 on hand but you may take a look of this webpage: http://www.alvechurchdata.co.uk/hints-and-tips/accaddtoolbar.html

It seems that "user-created" toolbars could be defined by handwritten code at `form.load` or somewhere similar. You may search `CommandBars.Add` and see if you can find those relevant code segments.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

In the design mode, you will be able to see the toolbar & actions assigned to each of the button.

Right click on the specific toolbar
Click on Customize...
Right click on the button you would like to edit the action of.

You will be able to see the action (which could either be macro or code).
Let me know, if that doesn't help at all.

Comment: Right click on the specific toolbar
Click on Customize...
Right click on the button you would like to edit the action of. aahhhh right click on the menu items on the toolbar! works wonders thanks for that tip